# Facebook Comment Code - What is it?

Tags: facebook

Recently I've seen some people using a string of code in their comment or wall post in order to do something interesting, such as hyperlinking the whole text. It looks quite fun though, but I don't know whether it's Facebook-defined code or any kind of language behind.

For example: `@@+[0:[158038637615605:0: YOUR TEXT HERE ]]`

I guess the number `158038637615605` could be an app's ID.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to be how Facebook is able to encode links in text without having to store any additional meta data. I assume they expect the format to be so strange as to not occur in a persons normal updates. The syntax was probably released by an engineer, or gleamed by someone examining the JavaScript operations as a user goes about tagging something.

A similar thing I've been seeing goes along the lines of:

> Your phone has a name. To figure it out, you take the last three digits of your phone number - for example 635 and type it the comment section of this post like `@*[635:0]` and then remove the `*` and post, and you get your phone's name.

I suspect they're making exceptions now to prevent the user from typing it manually.

Site note; `158038637615605` seems to be the ID of a [Facebook page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=158038637615605).